# Podcasts for Technician Test

Tags: united-states, license

Is there a podcast to listen to that teaches in-depth the technician class questions? All I could find is podcasts that just read the questions and answers. Is there a podcast that goes in-depth to every question and actually teaches the formulas/concepts?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the youtube video of Dan Romanchik with the slideshow that's based on the No-Nonsense Guide (by KB6NU). I downloaded it as an mp3 and it's the perfect "podcast"

I listen to the whole thing every day and now, 3 days later, I'm almost ready for the test!